# NextJS send email API not working on AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, smtp, gmail, aws-amplify

I have a NextJS that sends a request to an API route in Next too. The api sends an email using Gmails STMP. It works perfectly on localhost but on AWS amplify it's giving me this error:

```
[Error: 140058109941696:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:331:

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   ] {

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   library: 'SSL routines',

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   function: 'ssl3_get_record',

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   reason: 'wrong version number',

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   code: 'ESOCKET',

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   command: 'CONN'

2023-04-25T10:58:07.739-06:00   }
```

This the config I'm using for STMP:

```
SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
SMTP_PORT=465
```

And this is the API call I make from the web app itself:

```
await axios.post(
        "/api/email",
        {
          formData: {
           //...
          },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            console.log(
              "Upload Progress: " +
                Math.round(
                  (progressEvent.loaded / (progressEvent.total ?? 1)) * 100
                ) +
                "%"
            );
          },
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a proxy using Next's rewrites inside next.config to remove the httpS from the api call, since Amplify was trying to enforce it and it works now.